# Closure of set equals whole space property.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I’m writing some lecture notes for a Topology course i’m taking, and I try to include some extra problems I find online. However, I stumbled across this problem and can’t seem to write up a proof. The problem is as follows.

Let $(\mathbb{X}, \tau)$ be a Topological Space and let $A \subseteq \mathbb{X}$ such that $\overline{A} = \mathbb{X}$. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be open in $\mathbb{X}$. Prove that $\mathcal{O} \subseteq \overline{A \cap \mathcal{O}}$.

What I have been trying to do is the following:

Let $x \in \mathcal{O}$. Since $\mathcal{O} \subseteq \mathbb{X}$, we have that $x \in \mathbb{X} \implies x \in \overline{A}$, since $\mathbb{X} = \overline{A}$. Now, $x \in \overline{A} \implies \forall U, x \in U$ we have that $ A \cap U \neq \emptyset$.

This is where I get stuck and...I’m really not sure where to go.

I know an example of this problem is taking $\mathbb{X} = \mathbb{R}$, $A = \mathbb{Q}$, and say $ U = (0,1)$.

Any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x \in O$. you have to show that $x$ is in the closure of $O \cap A$. For this you have to show that if $U$ is an open set contaning $x$ then $U \cap O\cap A$ is not empty. Now $U \cap O$ is an  open set containing $x$ and $x \in \overline A$. Hence $A$ intersects $ O\cap U$.

Comment: Great! I see exactly where i was getting mixed up.